Why is my approach wrong for this probability question?
I came across the following question:

You roll a fair $40$-sided and fair $60$-sided dice.
What is the probability that the number on the $60$-sided dice is strictly larger than that on the $40$-sided dice?

I thought this was very similar to the tricky (but ultimately easy) problem wherein A tosses $n+1$ coins and B tosses $n$ coins, and you're asked to find the probability that A wins. You can use conditional probability to set yourself up for a symmetry argument.
Similarly, I did the following
Let $X_{60} =$ value of 60-sided dice, and $X_{40} =$ value of 40-sided dice. Then,
$P(X_{60} > X_{40}) = P(X_{60}>X_{40}|X_{60}\leq40)\cdot{P(X_{60}\leq 40)} + P(X_{60}>X_{40}|X_{60}>40)\cdot{P(X_{60}>40)}$
By symmetry, $P(X_{60}>X_{40}|X_{60}\leq40)=\frac{1}{2}$. So we have,
$P(X_{60} > X_{40}) = \frac{1}{2}\times{\frac{40}{60}} + \frac{20}{60} = \frac{2}{3}$.
But this is the incorrect answer.

Oh wait, I think I might have figured this out right as I posted the question. This is wrong because the symmetry argument doesn't apply here. In the case of the coins, if you disregard one of A's coins, you really have a symmetrical situation. Here, you can't say the same because for the 60-sided dice, the probabilities are out of 60, whereas for the other dice they are out of 40.

I'm a bit weak in combinatorics, but can we find when the 40 sided dice gives larger/equal values and then subtract from 1? Like if 60 faced dice lands on 1, there are 40 values which are more than/equal to it. We can continue this. 40+39+....+1=$\binom{41}{2}=820$ Total possible arrangements are 40×60=2400. Hence the answer should come to $$1-\frac{820}{2400}=\frac{79}{120}$$ But I maybe wrong, hence I gave it as a comment

That is the correct answer!

I completely agree with your initial analysis, and (in fact) the case of $~p(X_{60}) > 40~$ is completely dealt with by assigning this the probability of $~(1/3).$
Your mistake was in overlooking that in the $~(2/3)~$ of the time that $~p(X_{60}) \leq 40,~$ you have (in general) a $~(1/40)~$ probability that the two dice will be the same.  In the $~(39/40)~$ of the time that the two dice are then different, then by symmetry, the probability is $~(1/2)~$ that $~X_{60}~$ is greater.
This leads to the overall computation of
$$(1/3) + \left[ ~(2/3) \times (39/40) \times (1/2) ~\right].$$

Thank you very much! Interesting. So my reasoning for why I was wrong ... was, in turn, wrong. This approach works like a charm!

\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{m = 1}^{40}{1 \over 40}\sum_{n = m + 1}^{60}{1 \over 60}}
= {1 \over 2400}\sum_{m = 1}^{40}\left(60 - m\right) =
{60 \times 40 - 40 \times 41/2 \over 2400}
\\[5mm] = & \ \color{#44f}{79 \over 120} \approx 0.6583
\end{align}
